# Sunspot running on windows with rails 

Tags: sunspot-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I followed the instruction and installed the sunspot_rails gem

when I do

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

it tells me

```
This command is not supported on i386-mingw32. Use rake sunspot:solr:run to run Solr in the foreground.
```

when I use that command I get

```
** Invoke sunspot:solr:run (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:solr:run
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
rake aborted!
You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:202:in `ensure_java_installed'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:27:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:23:in `new'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:run
```

I am running windows 7 x64. 
sunspot won't run on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved..

Thought it was a java issue, but even after I installed java it won't work.

I found the answer (which apparently shouldn't be an issue with latest push of sunspot..)

the latest push fixed the issue
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/commit/721d3419492852533764d58f2c7f398687891a94

since bundler apparently didn't fetch me the latest, I changed it manually and it now works..

Comment: nice, thanks for this fix! had been scratching my head bout hits one, you saved me some time with this :)

Comment: how do you stop this? because when you started it and you click crtl c or crtl scroll lock you stop it in cmd but the service is not stopped